# lightswitch installation error

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-lightswitch

So we are having an issue on some client machines, when we go to the url to install a Lightswitch desktop app(VS2013), the install starts the counter goes to 80-90% and then we get an error message saying it failed to install to restart application and try again. At this point if we right click inside the browser window, we get a menu with option to install the app. And the app gets installed fine. However I am not able to figure out why we get the error which seems to be a silverlight issue.

Comment: Any chance the install url is https? We've hit an issue where the auto-generated install page has http links to the MS Silverlight website, and the cross-protocol conflict causes the install to fail (may depend on individual browser security setttings).